# Javascript translation not working

Tags: javascript, localisation, magento-2.1.3

I have override the register template in my custom theme. In this form use the validation to validate my fields but the translation of the error messages aren't showed.

I declare the function where I validate my fields by :

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/mage',
        'mage/validation'
    ], function ($) {
        var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        ...
        if (dataForm.validation('isValid')) {
           ...
        }
        ...
});
```

I cleared caches, deploy static content by the language I used, remove js-translation.json to regenerate it (it is well regenerated with all js string content to translate)...

My translations are in my theme app/design/frontend/Vendor/themeName/i18n/xx_XX.csv

Comment: Did you use like  **$.mage.__('Your message here')**  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like below code. This is just example.

```
require([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui', 
'mage/translate'
], function($){ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert($.mage.__('Your Message'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it works but why validation are not translated ? it's the problem the strings I generate with translations and base string translations are not translated